# Secure path in Android FileSystem?

Tags: android, file

I want to save my Android Application images and their details files in some secure path (so that any Android Application user can't access that files or you can say that it should be hidden to the User).

Can Anyone Help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the device is rooted, the user will have an access to any file. If not, you can use [internal storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal).

Accessing the chache or files folder is done using the Context. the context can be your activity (activity extends context), and if you want to access the directory from a class which is not your activity / service you will need to pass a reference of the activity to this class.

Short example:

```
File chacheDir = myActivity.getCacheDir();
```

Comment: Sorry I want the Secure directory path and I found getCacheDir() how to use getCacheDir() ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder with start with "."filename(ignore quotes) this will be always hidden to the user since android is linux based file system. you can store all your image into that folder.

Comment: Sorry I want the Secure directory path and I found getCacheDir() how to use getCacheDir() ?

Comment: you can only access this for your app use context.getCacheDir();